# HTTPS page not loaded on BrowserContent

Tags: blackberry

I am implementing an embedded browser in my app, and because it has to be compatible with OS 4.0, [BrowserContent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field/BrowserContent.html) is my only choice.

When opening a HTTPS page the screen is blank, but this problem doesn't occur when a [BrowserSession](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/BrowserSession.html) is used.  So I put a println after the BrowserContent part, and it doesn't show up in the console output. So I think this is something wrong with that.

```
class BrowserScreen extends MainScreen {
    private RenderingSession _renderingSession;
    private HttpsConnection _connection;

    public BrowserScreen(String url) {
        _renderingSession = RenderingSession.getNewInstance();
        final String _url = url;

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    _connection = 
                        (HttpsConnection)Connector.open(_url, Connector.READ, true);
                    BrowserContent content = 
                        _renderingSession.getBrowserContent(_connection, null, 0);
                    content.finishLoading();
                    Field field = content.getDisplayableContent();

                    synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {  
                        add(field);
                    }
                } catch (Exception  e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the sample, and the BB people have done nothing in this regards for years.. You will never know that your page is not rendered and you will be redirected to the calling page all by itself. When they are unable to render the page they insert a redirection code in the HTTP response  instead of giving a render exception (check it out in the inputstream and convert it into string and you shall know), and the intended page is never shown. They have resolved this in 5.0 and higher using BrowserField, but we need solution for the low end mobiles.