# Browser filed issue in storm device of blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am using a browser field,and it is getting displayed in the simulator 4.7 storm.But when i execute on device,it remains blank and the page is not displayed.can anyone help.

Comment: I removed the long RIM demo code attached.  Please just provide a link if you haven't changed the demo code at all.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a 9800 w/ 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,i tried appending ";interface=true" to the url still its not executing on 9550 device,whereas in 9550 simulator its executing

/*
 * BrowserFieldDemo.java 
 * 
 * Copyright © 1998-2009 Research In Motion Ltd.
 * 
 * Note: For the sake of simplicity, this sample application may not leverage
 * resource bundles and resource strings.  However, it is STRONGLY recommended
 * that application developers make use of the localization features available
 * within the BlackBerry development platform to ensure a seamless application
 * experience across a variety of languages and geographies.  For more information
 * on localizing your application, please refer to the BlackBerry Java Development
 * Environment Development Guide associated with this release.
 */

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.browser.field.*;
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpHeaders;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Status;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;

final class BrowserFieldDemo extends UiApplication implements RenderingApplication 
{

```
private static final String REFERER = "referer";   

private RenderingSession _renderingSession;   
private HttpConnection  _currentConnection;
private MainScreen _mainScreen;


/***************************************************************************
 * Main.
 **************************************************************************/
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    BrowserFieldDemo app = new BrowserFieldDemo();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}

private BrowserFieldDemo() 
{        

    _mainScreen = new MainScreen();        
    pushScreen(_mainScreen);
    _renderingSession = RenderingSession.getNewInstance();

    // Enable javascript.
    //_renderingSession.getRenderingOptions().setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID, RenderingOptions.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, true);                        

    PrimaryResourceFetchThread thread = new PrimaryResourceFetchThread("http://wwww.vensi.com"+";interface=true", null, null, null, this);
    thread.start();                       

}

void processConnection(HttpConnection connection, Event e) 
{
    // Cancel previous request.
    if (_currentConnection != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            _currentConnection.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
        }
    }

    _currentConnection = connection;

    BrowserContent browserContent = null;

    try 
    {
        browserContent = _renderingSession.getBrowserContent(connection, this, e);

        if (browserContent != null) 
        {
            Field field = browserContent.getDisplayableContent();

            if (field != null) 
            {
                synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) 
                {
                    _mainScreen.deleteAll();
                    _mainScreen.add(field);
                }
            }

            browserContent.finishLoading();
        }

    } 
    catch (RenderingException re) 
    {
    } 
    finally 
    {
        SecondaryResourceFetchThread.doneAddingImages();
    }

}    

/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#eventOccurred(net.rim.device.api.browser.Event)
 */
public Object eventOccurred(Event event) 
{
    int eventId = event.getUID();

    switch (eventId) 
    {
        case Event.EVENT_URL_REQUESTED : 
        {
            UrlRequestedEvent urlRequestedEvent = (UrlRequestedEvent) event;    

            PrimaryResourceFetchThread thread = new PrimaryResourceFetchThread(urlRequestedEvent.getURL(),
                                                                                     urlRequestedEvent.getHeaders(), 
                                                                                     urlRequestedEvent.getPostData(),
                                                                                     event, this);
            thread.start();

            break;

        } 
        case Event.EVENT_BROWSER_CONTENT_CHANGED: 
        {                
            // Browser field title might have changed update title.
            BrowserContentChangedEvent browserContentChangedEvent = (BrowserContentChangedEvent) event; 

            if (browserContentChangedEvent.getSource() instanceof BrowserContent) 
            { 
                BrowserContent browserField = (BrowserContent) browserContentChangedEvent.getSource(); 
                String newTitle = browserField.getTitle();
                if (newTitle != null) 
                {
                    synchronized (getAppEventLock()) 
                    { 
                        _mainScreen.setTitle(newTitle);
                    }                                               
                }                                       
            }                   

            break;                

        } 
        case Event.EVENT_REDIRECT : 
        {
            RedirectEvent e = (RedirectEvent) event;
            String referrer = e.getSourceURL();

            switch (e.getType()) 
            {  
                case RedirectEvent.TYPE_SINGLE_FRAME_REDIRECT :
                    // Show redirect message.
                    Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            Status.show("You are being redirected to a different page...");
                        }
                    });

                break;

                case RedirectEvent.TYPE_JAVASCRIPT :
                    break;

                case RedirectEvent.TYPE_META :
                    // MSIE and Mozilla don't send a Referer for META Refresh.
                    referrer = null;     
                    break;

                case RedirectEvent.TYPE_300_REDIRECT :
                    // MSIE, Mozilla, and Opera all send the original
                    // request's Referer as the Referer for the new
                    // request.
                    Object eventSource = e.getSource();
                    if (eventSource instanceof HttpConnection) 
                    {
                        referrer = ((HttpConnection)eventSource).getRequestProperty(REFERER);
                    }

                    break;
                }

                HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                requestHeaders.setProperty(REFERER, referrer);
                PrimaryResourceFetchThread thread = new PrimaryResourceFetchThread(e.getLocation(), requestHeaders,null, event, this);
                thread.start();
                break;

        } 
        case Event.EVENT_CLOSE :
            // TODO: close the appication
            break;

        case Event.EVENT_SET_HEADER :        // No cache support.
        case Event.EVENT_SET_HTTP_COOKIE :   // No cookie support.
        case Event.EVENT_HISTORY :           // No history support.
        case Event.EVENT_EXECUTING_SCRIPT :  // No progress bar is supported.
        case Event.EVENT_FULL_WINDOW :       // No full window support.
        case Event.EVENT_STOP :              // No stop loading support.
        default :
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#getAvailableHeight(net.rim.device.api.browser.BrowserContent)
 */
public int getAvailableHeight(BrowserContent browserField) 
{
    // Field has full screen.
    return Display.getHeight();
}

/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#getAvailableWidth(net.rim.device.api.browser.BrowserContent)
 */
public int getAvailableWidth(BrowserContent browserField) 
{
    // Field has full screen.
    return Display.getWidth();
}

/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#getHistoryPosition(net.rim.device.api.browser.BrowserContent)
 */
public int getHistoryPosition(BrowserContent browserField) 
{
    // No history support.
    return 0;
}


/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#getHTTPCookie(java.lang.String)
 */
public String getHTTPCookie(String url) 
{
    // No cookie support.
    return null;
}

/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#getResource(net.rim.device.api.browser.RequestedResource,
 *      net.rim.device.api.browser.BrowserContent)
 */
public HttpConnection getResource( RequestedResource resource, BrowserContent referrer) 
{
    if (resource == null) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Check if this is cache-only request.
    if (resource.isCacheOnly()) 
    {
        // No cache support.
        return null;
    }

    String url = resource.getUrl();

    if (url == null) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    // If referrer is null we must return the connection.
    if (referrer == null) 
    {
        HttpConnection connection = Utilities.makeConnection(resource.getUrl(), resource.getRequestHeaders(), null);

        return connection;

    } 
    else 
    {
        // If referrer is provided we can set up the connection on a separate thread.
        SecondaryResourceFetchThread.enqueue(resource, referrer);
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @see net.rim.device.api.browser.RenderingApplication#invokeRunnable(java.lang.Runnable)
 */
public void invokeRunnable(Runnable runnable) 
{       
    (new Thread(runnable)).start();
}
```

}

class PrimaryResourceFetchThread extends Thread 
{

```
private BrowserFieldDemo _application;
private Event _event;
private byte[] _postData;
private HttpHeaders _requestHeaders;
private String _url;

PrimaryResourceFetchThread(String url, HttpHeaders requestHeaders, byte[] postData, 
                              Event event, BrowserFieldDemo application) 
{
    _url = url;
    _requestHeaders = requestHeaders;
    _postData = postData;
    _application = application;
    _event = event;
}

public void run() 
{
    HttpConnection connection = Utilities.makeConnection(_url, _requestHeaders, _postData);
    _application.processConnection(connection, _event);        
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in the sample, and the BB people have done nothing in this regards for years.. You will never know that your page is not rendered and you will be redirected to the calling page all by itself. When they are unable to render the page they insert a redirection code in the HTTP response  instead of giving a render exception (check it out in the inputstream and convert it into string and you shall know), and the intended page is never shown. They have resolved this in 5.0 and higher using BrowserField, but we need solution for the low end mobiles.

Comment: Dude (Abhinav), you can't just copy-paste your old answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093634/https-page-not-loaded-on-browsercontent like that.